# How to display ArrayList Strings in TextView

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I need to display current values in TextView (after removing String). I'm adding String when button is On and I need to remove it, when it's Off ( I don't know if I do it well), next I need to display Strings in TextView without deleted String. I need to display only Strings from On buttons.I don't know how to display ArrayList in TextView - this code display.setText(mActiveToggles.toString()); doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
public class Calc extends ActionBarActivity {

TextView display;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);

    display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    display.setText("Add item");
}

static boolean isempty=true;

public void changeButton(View sender) {
ToggleButton btn = (ToggleButton) sender;

ArrayList<String> mActiveToggles = new ArrayList<String>();

String b = btn.getText().toString();

boolean on = ((ToggleButton) sender).isChecked();

if(on) {
    if (isempty) {
        if (b.equals("0")) return;
        display.setText(btn.getText());
        mActiveToggles.add(b);
        isempty = false;
    } else {
        display.append(btn.getText());
        mActiveToggles.add(b);
    }
}
else
{
    if (b.equals(btn.getText()))
    {
        mActiveToggles.remove(b);
        display.setText(mActiveToggles.toString());

    }
}
```

}

Comment: I don't see a question.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to display ArrayList in TextView - this code display.setText(mActiveToggles.toString()); doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop. Iterate over each element in the ArrayList to add it to a String (or if you prefer you can use a StringBuilder instead). It would look something like the following:

```
String activeToggles = "";

for (String s : mActiveToggles) {
    activeToggles += s + " ";
}

display.setText(activeToggles);
```

Comment: I used it, but if my Toggle is Off TextView is empty.

Comment: Step through your code in debug mode. Make sure mActiveToggles contains some data and that your logic is functioning as intended.

Comment: I can't solve this problem...
Maybe somebody has an idea to only display Toggles which are On?